# same template for both regular pointer and shared_ptr

Tags: c++11

I have a template in C++ like below

```
template <class TYPE>
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<TYPE*> entityPtr){
    if(entityPtr.size()== 0) return true;
    ...
}
```

I want to use the same template for `std::shared_ptr`; i.e. I have `std::vector<std::shared_ptr>;`

How can I use the same template?

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood the question but can't you just remove the * from the tempaltised function? Something like:

```
class Base {};

template <class Type>
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type> entityPtr){
    if(entityPtr.size()== 0) return true;
    //...
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec_shared;
    std::vector<int*> vec_intp;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec_unique_ptr;
    writeRecordForSet(vec_shared);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_intp);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_unique_ptr);
}
```

This way you could use both `vector<type*>` as well as `vector<shared_ptr>` as arguments to the function. (Or any other pointer type like unique_ptr)

Comment: error C2784: 'bool SM_OutputFormatop2::writeRecordForSet(std::vector<TYPE*,std::allocator<_Ty>>)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::vector<TYPE*,std::allocator<_Ty>>' from 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SM_PressureLoad>,std::allocator<_Ty>>'

Comment: error C2784: 'bool SM_OutputFormatop2::writeRecordForSet(std::vector<TYPE*,std::allocator<_Ty>>)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::vector<TYPE*,std::allocator<_Ty>>' from 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SM_PressureLoad>,std::allocator<_Ty>>'

Comment: wait wait wait ; Let me verify

Comment: Well this one does not work               class Base {
public: 
 int getVal() { return 0; }
};

template <class Type>
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type> entityPtr) {
 if (entityPtr.size() == 0) return true;
 //...
 for (auto iter = entityPtr.begin(); iter != entityPtr.end(); iter++) {
  Type enPtr = *iter;
  int myval = enPtr->getVal();
 }

 return true;
}

int main() {
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec_shared;
 std::vector<int*> vec_intp;
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec_unique_ptr;
 writeRecordForSet(vec_shared);
 writeRecordForSet(vec_intp);
}

Comment: You need `Type& enPtr = *iter;` to allow for `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, and `enPtr->getVal()` is invalid if `enPtr` is an `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
This one does not work 
   class Base {
   public: 
       int getVal() { return 0; }
   };

   template <class Type>
   bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type> entityPtr) {
    if (entityPtr.size() == 0) return true;
    //...
    for (auto iter = entityPtr.begin(); iter != entityPtr.end(); iter++) {
        Type enPtr = *iter;
        int myval = enPtr->getVal();
    }

    return true;
   }

   int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec_shared;
    std::vector<int*> vec_intp;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec_unique_ptr;
    writeRecordForSet(vec_shared);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_intp);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_unique_ptr);
   }
```